# Google Sheet Query Count working, but other functions are not (e.g., sum, avg)

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, google-query-language

I want to count / sum / average various data points based on many criteria.

One of the criteria at least one of the touchpoints falls between two set dates. There are five potential touchpoints. Each potential touch point has a column.

I created this query that works with count

```
`=QUERY(B10:G,"Select count (B) 
where B<5 AND 
(C >= date '"&TEXT(C9, "e-m-d")&"'AND C <= date '"&TEXT(D9, "e-m-d")&"')
Or (D >= date '"&TEXT(C9, "e-m-d")&"'AND D <= date '"&TEXT(D9, "e-m-d")&"')
Or (E >= date '"&TEXT(C9, "e-m-d")&"'AND E <= date '"&TEXT(D9, "e-m-d")&"')
Or (F >= date '"&TEXT(C9, "e-m-d")&"'AND F <= date '"&TEXT(D9, "e-m-d")&"')
Or (G >= date '"&TEXT(C9, "e-m-d")&"'AND G <= date '"&TEXT(D9, "e-m-d")&"')
label count(B) ''", 0)`
```

However, when I use other funchtions it does not work

```
`=QUERY(B10:G,"Select Sum(B) 
where B<5 AND 
(C >= date '"&TEXT(C9, "e-m-d")&"'AND C <= date '"&TEXT(D9, "e-m-d")&"')
Or (D >= date '"&TEXT(C9, "e-m-d")&"'AND D <= date '"&TEXT(D9, "e-m-d")&"')
Or (E >= date '"&TEXT(C9, "e-m-d")&"'AND E <= date '"&TEXT(D9, "e-m-d")&"')
Or (F >= date '"&TEXT(C9, "e-m-d")&"'AND F <= date '"&TEXT(D9, "e-m-d")&"')
Or (G >= date '"&TEXT(C9, "e-m-d")&"'AND G <= date '"&TEXT(D9, "e-m-d")&"')
label count(B) ''", 0)`
```

This is what the data looks like: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1BiWsm6uPncPsdM7WiVDdRSbkUcbulNLhITqbt4rqXB8/edit?usp=sharing

```
Start   End         
1/1/23  1/31/23
```

| Number | Screening | F1 | F2 | F3 | F4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1/1/23 | 1/4/23 | 1/6/23 | 1/8/23 | 1/10/23 |
| 2 | 12/03/22 | 1/4/23 | 02/05/23 | 3/9/23 | 04/10/23 |
| 3 | 1/7/23 | 1/8/23 | 1/9/23 | 1/10/23 | 1/11/23 |
| 4 | 09/22/22 | 10/28/22 | 12/03/22 | 1/10/23 | 02/17/23 |

I searched this site and tried other formulas

Comment: Your second formula is also correct. Only change label clause `count(B)` to `sum(B)`.

Comment: Note that [your email address can also be accessed by the public](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/394304), if you share Google files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Check the Label Statement

In your second formula where you wanted to get the sum of values in column B, change the `label count(B)` to `label sum(B)`. Thus, the formula should look like:

For Sum:

```
=QUERY(B10:G,"Select Sum(B) 
where B<5 AND 
((C >= date '"&TEXT(C9, "e-m-d")&"'AND C <= date '"&TEXT(D9, "e-m-d")&"')
Or (D >= date '"&TEXT(C9, "e-m-d")&"'AND D <= date '"&TEXT(D9, "e-m-d")&"')
Or (E >= date '"&TEXT(C9, "e-m-d")&"'AND E <= date '"&TEXT(D9, "e-m-d")&"')
Or (F >= date '"&TEXT(C9, "e-m-d")&"'AND F <= date '"&TEXT(D9, "e-m-d")&"')
Or (G >= date '"&TEXT(C9, "e-m-d")&"'AND G <= date '"&TEXT(D9, "e-m-d")&"'))
label Sum(B) ''", 0)
```

For Avg:

```
=QUERY(B10:G,"Select Avg(B) 
where B<5 AND 
((C >= date '"&TEXT(C9, "e-m-d")&"'AND C <= date '"&TEXT(D9, "e-m-d")&"')
Or (D >= date '"&TEXT(C9, "e-m-d")&"'AND D <= date '"&TEXT(D9, "e-m-d")&"')
Or (E >= date '"&TEXT(C9, "e-m-d")&"'AND E <= date '"&TEXT(D9, "e-m-d")&"')
Or (F >= date '"&TEXT(C9, "e-m-d")&"'AND F <= date '"&TEXT(D9, "e-m-d")&"')
Or (G >= date '"&TEXT(C9, "e-m-d")&"'AND G <= date '"&TEXT(D9, "e-m-d")&"'))
label Avg(B) ''", 0)
```

The same concept is applicable to other functions (i.e. min, max, etc.) Always take note that when using these formulas, you should also take a look at the label.

Answer (score 1):

***Alternate formula:*** (incase if you do not wish to have a date-condition check for each column separately within query function)

```
=sum(ifna(filter(B12:B,
                       B12:B<5,
                       byrow(C12:G,lambda(Σ,if(counta(Σ)=0,,sum(index(if((Σ>=C9)*(Σ<=D9),1,))))))<>0)))
```

- you may only replace the `sum` part **used at the starting point** of formula  with `average` or `counta` for diff. aggregate calculations.

[image]